# How to add a custom thumbnail size for a specific category?

Tags: categories, functions, thumbnails

The default thumbnail size for the Wordpress theme I use generates category thumbnails for the homepage and archive page at 200x110px. I would like to add a custom thumbnail size for a specific category of 200x200px that would display on the homepage and on the category archive page. I have experience working with Wordpress but I am not an expert. Based on the responses I've read to similar questions, I believe the answer lies in functions.php but I need detailed instructions on how to achieve this. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set featured image size for a custom post type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32811/set-featured-image-size-for-a-custom-post-type)

Comment: How does the Theme generate the thumbnails for your Categories? That's nothing built into WP by default. Please show the relevant code lines.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code on your functions.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'clonecell_theme_setup' );
function clonecell_theme_setup() {
    /* Set Default Image Sizes*/
    add_image_size( 'mini-thumbnail', 50, 50, true ); // for clonecell recent post widget
}
```

Or if you already have an action hook on `after_theme_setup`,put the `add_image_size` on that function.

Add another `add_image_size` using this format

```
add_image_size($name, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: You don't need to use a callback for add_image_size(). You can call it directly within your functions file.

Comment: My theme does seem to have an action hook on after_theme_setup: add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ar2_setup', 10 );

Comment: This code is in my theme's functions.php:add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ar2_setup', 10 );

if ( !function_exists('ar2_setup') ) :

Comment: My theme does have an action hook on after_theme_setup. So, do I insert the code you provided for add_image_size immediately below that, with the height and width set to 200? I just don't want to do anything that will cause an error. Also, how is this thumbnail size called for a specific category for both the homepage and archive pages? I don't see anything in the code that would associate the custom thumbnail size with a category. @ifdion

Comment: @Bodhitree you can put it inside or outside the `ar2_setup()` referring to @Brian 's comment. After you add the image size in functions.php, open the template you use for homepage & archive and replace the image size on the functions that call the post thumbnail with your new size. Last step, rebuild the thumbnails using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

Comment: @ifdion, thanks for your advice but I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. I do not want to change the theme's default thumbnail size. What I want is to have two different thumbnail sizes: I want to use the theme's default thumbnail size of 200x110 for every category except one. For just one category, I want to display a thumbnail of 200x200, on the homepage and that category's archive page. Is that what your code will accomplish? Thanks again!

Comment: I am pretty sure, we are talking about the same thing. First of all, the `add_image_size` does not change the default thumbnail size. Let say your category slug, the one needs a different thumbnail size, is `cute-cat` than the function can goes like `add_image_size('cute-cat-thumbs', 200,200,true)`. Next on the category-cute-cat.php template file, change the thumbnail size to `cute-cat-thumbs`. This last part is rather vague, since I have no idea how you template look like.